# VueJS - Creating a Counter Up Time with Start, Pause, Resume and Stop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

I have problem with counter up resume function.

for example:
if the timer paused at **00:00:03** and then, the next view seconds later (eg: 5 seconds later) I clicked the resume button.
It suppose to be continue from **00:00:04**.
But the timer start from *00:00:08*.

I have no idea how to fix this.

here's the codes: https://jsitor.com/pVz84uaY3

Answer (score 0):

it's doing exactly what you wanted, you are always calculating against variable with time started `this.diff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - this.actv_date.getTime());` the `actv_date`

for resume functionality you have to save "time elapsed" and on resume calculate `this.actv_date = today.getTime() - timeElapsed` to hold original dif